# How do target an API level for android from config.xml for phonegap?

Tags: android, phonegap-build, google-developers-console

I used to build apps with the basic config.xml file for phonegap for play store until recently when my apps were being rejected because they did not target API level 26. I did some research and and tried a few [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/login?ssrc=head&returnurl=https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F27135185%2Fhow-can-i-specify-the-minimum-sdk-in-phonegap-it-is-ignoring-android-minsdkvers) and did this:

```
<platform name="android">
    <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="26" />
    <preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="26" />
</platform>
```

which went from bad to worse, my apps in debug mode (after xompilation on phonegap build) won't even be parsed on android anymore.

I have equally read a couple of solutions but none seems to walk. I really just want to know what I should be including into the config.xml file so that I can going anew.

Answer (score 0):

My config.xml file has these two lines but they are placed outside of

`<platform name="android"></platform>`

Here are the values that I use and my app is live on both Apple and Google app store:

```
<preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="26" />
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="14" />
```

Let me know if you want an example of my full config.xml file! :)